# ActiveX component - Word manipulation replacement

Tags: javascript, ms-word, ms-office, activex

Currently I got a ~12 year old web application that uses an ActiveX. I need to replace the ActiveX component due to browser compatibility problems. The ActiveX is currently in use to (on the client side):

```
   1. Replaces values from the database to bookmarks on a MS Word document.
   2. Manipulate the Word object even after the end user has modify it.
   3. Save the Word document on a network share.
```

I have seen other third party components that manipulate MS Word but only on the server side.

I also took a look at Office Javascript API but it seems that is for making plugins within the Office Apps instead on manipulating it from outside.

Any idea what technology exists today to replace that non secure ActiveX?

Answer (score -1):

Well, it depends on the your needs (document formats). If you deal only with open XML based documents (*.docx) you may consider using the Open XML SDK for that. See [Welcome to the Open XML SDK 2.5 for Office](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for more information.

Also you may consider third-party components designed for server-side execution.